# S3 bucket listing files (only) located in multiple folders, without listing folders

Tags: amazon-s3

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(
    new ListObjectsRequest()
    .withBucketName(bucketName)
    .withPrefix("img/1/abc/")
);

for(S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary: objectListing.getObjectSummaries())
    System.out.println(("Listing all the files: " + s3ObjectSummary.getKey()));
```

Can anybody help me... I want to list only files available in multiple folders.

> img/1/abc/ios-2x/a@2X.jpg--yes
>
> img/1/abc/ios-2x_$folder$---no
>
> img/1/abc/ios-3x/b@3X.jpg---yes
>
> img/1/abc/ios-3x_$folder$---no
>
> img/1/abc/xxhdpi/c@2x.jpg---yes
>
> img/1/abc/xxhdpi/c.jpg--yes
>
> img/1/abc/xxhdpi_$folder$---no

I am using java for listing the objects inside S3, I can do iterate over the folders to get desired result. but was looking for doing the same by using single loop and result will not give folder results.

Comment: have managed to ignore it..   if(keyList.get(i).matches("*_\$folder\$.*")) {
                continue;
            }

Comment: (img/1/abc/ios-2x_$folder$) folder gets created ...when we use third party tool(like S3fox for firefox) to access S3 bucket, So it is recommended to use aws console to prevent such kind of confusion. Thanks